# Highcharts only loads Title / Subtitle

Tags: highcharts, load

As the title states, highcharts is only loading the title and subtitle, yet none of the subsequent chart information or it's relevant theme. Hitting my head against a wall trying to get this to work. Really hoping someone else here has had this problem.

[jsfidizzle](http://jsfiddle.net/jn4ne8ne/1/)

The first half of the fiddle is the highcharts theme. All the logic starts kicking off at `#transitfunding`

Answer (score 5):

Very simple fix... you need to move your `series` data outside of your `plotOptions:` like so:

```
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            },

        },
        series: [{
                name: 'Other',
                data: [0, 0, -5400000, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 8016805, -8435419, -28900000]
            }, {
                name: 'Gas Tax',
                data: [119221, 627705, 234646, 6685080, 1341871, 1990937, 3187208, 6911715, 10002605, -14282137, -10555715 ]
            }]
```

A working fiddle can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jn4ne8ne/4/).

Answer (score 1):

you have misplace the series section.

series(that contains data) is the sibling of plotOptions not its child.

so it should be like

```
plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            },
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Other',
            data: [0, 0, -5400000, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 8016805, -8435419, -28900000]
        }, {
            name: 'Gas Tax',
            data: [119221, 627705, 234646, 6685080, 1341871, 1990937, 3187208, 6911715, 10002605, -14282137, -10555715 ]
        }]
```

I've updated your js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jn4ne8ne/5/)

Comment: is this not just a copy of my original answer?

Comment: sorry aus_lacy I've seen your answer after I've posted mine